# How to use between in MySQL ansi query?

Tags: mysql, join, between, ansi-sql

I need to query something using INNER JOIN, how can I use `WHERE user_id between 2000 and 3000` inside ANSI query

e.g.

```
SELECT table1.name, table2.wage, table2.bonus table3.shift, table4.vacation
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.userid = table2.userid
INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.userid = table3.userid
INNER JOIN table4 ON table4.userid = table4.userid 
LEFT JOIN table5 ON table1.name = table5.position
```

also, I need to limit table2.wage between 2000 and 4000 how can I represent it

Answer (score 1):

Well, `a BETWEEN x AND y` is nothing else then `( a >= x AND a <= y )`, so

```
WHERE ( user_id >= 2000 AND user_id <= 3000 )
```

should do

Comment: can i put where in ANSI query where exactly i put it